# why am i getting Resource id #5 error in mysql_query?

Tags: php, mysql, resources

i'm trying to do a `mysql_query` but i am getting a resource id #5 error.
this is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT id_spieler FROM tblSpieler WHERE name = '$winner'";
ECHO "sql is $winner";

$sql2 = mysql_query($sql) or die("Anfrage Spieler nicht erfolgreich");
ECHO "sql2 is $sql2";
```

this is what i am getting with the echo commands:

```
sql is SELECT id_spieler FROM tblSpieler WHERE name = 'Peter'
sql2 is Resource id #5
```

why am i getting the resource id error? it should get me a '2'. In `phpmyadmin` the query works.........

Comment: That's correct. You should call `mysql_fetch_array($sql2)` to get the result set(s).

Comment: sorry, i'm new to php. what would be the full correct command?

Comment: You have to read the documentation of mysql_query and mysql_fetch_array. There are a lot examples.